# C++ unique_ptr; Why this sample codes get compile error?? error codes are so long that I can't specify it

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I'm studying about smart pointer now, and I just built the sample codes in the book.
But when I use `unique_ptr` like this code below, it makes compile error. The error codes are so long that they are almost cut, so I can't write down them all.

I wonder why this codes got error... please help me.

`compiler and OS : g++ (Ubuntu 9.1.0-2ubuntu2~18.04) 9.1.0`

error codes that i could found

```
/workspace/What_I_Learned/Cpp/53/53-4.cpp:23:30: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ and ‘std::unique_ptr<int>’)
   23 |  cout << "smart pointer 2: " << p2 << '\n';
      |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~~
      |       |                         |
      |       std::basic_ostream<char>  std::unique_ptr<int>

/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:691:5: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, std::basic_ostream<char>&>’
```

codes i wrote down

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    unique_ptr<int> p1(new int(10));
    unique_ptr<int> p2;
    
    cout << "smart pointer 1: " << p1 << '\n';
    cout << "smart pointer 2: " << p2 << '\n';
    cout << "move to p2\n";
    
    p2 = move(p1);
    
    cout << "smart pointer 1: " << p1 << '\n';
    cout << "smart pointer 2: " << p2 << '\n';
    cout << "free memory\n";
    
    p2.reset();
    
    cout << "smart pointer 1: " << p1 << '\n';
    cout << "smart pointer 2: " << p2 << '\n';
}
```

I already tried `-std=g++11` and `-std=g++14`.

Comment: Rather than providing the LAST error message from the compiler (the one at the bottom of your screen or window), provide the FIRST error message.    That is likely to be more informative about the cause of your problem.     Generally speaking, as a compiler encounters more errors in your code, it becomes more confused - which means that error messages after the first are more likely to be unclear.    In any event, C++ iostreams do not support input or output of `std::unique_ptr`s.

Comment: What do you want printed? The address or the contents? (Which book, btw?)

Comment: Are you trying to print the pointer itself? Then use e.g. `p1.get()`. Or create an `<<` overload taking a `std::unique_ptr` template as the second argument (by (constant) reference!) and uses its `get` function to get the raw pointer.

Comment: @Peter Thank you for the information. I wanted to wrote all of the errors from first to last, but it was too long that the console window cut it almost 80%... I could'nt paste it.

Comment: @doctorlove the address is what i want to print.. and actually it was the book of the lesson that i'm taking in my country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `operator <<` for an object of the type `std::unique_otr`.

If you need to output the value of the owned pointer then write

```
cout << "smart pointer 1: " << p1.get() << '\n';
```

If the template argument of the class template `std::unique_ptr` is `char` then you need to cast the returned expression of the member function `get` to the type `void *`. For example

```
cout << "smart pointer 1: " << static_cast<void *>( p1.get() ) << '\n';
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main() 
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> p1(new int( 10 ) );
    std::unique_ptr<char> p2( new char( 'A') );
    
    std::cout << "smart pointer 1: " << p1.get() << '\n';
    std::cout << "smart pointer 2: " << static_cast<void *>( p2.get() ) << '\n';
}
```

The program output might look like

```
smart pointer 1: 0x5593824d6e70
smart pointer 2: 0x5593824d6e90
```

If the owned pointer of an object of the type `std::unique_ptr<char>` is outputted without casting then it will be outputted as a C string instead of outputting its stored value (address).

If you need to output the pointed value of an object of the class template `std::unique_ptr` then just apply the dereference operator.

For example

```
cout << "smart pointer 1: " << *p1 << '\n';
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main() 
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> p1(new int( 10 ) );
    std::unique_ptr<char> p2( new char( 'A') );
    
    std::cout << "the value of the smart pointer 1: " << *p1 << '\n';
    std::cout << "the value of the smart pointer 2: " << *p2 << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
the value of the smart pointer 1: 10
the value of the smart pointer 2: A
```

Before outputting a pointed value you can check whether the object of the class template `std::unique_ptr` does not store a null pointer like

```
if ( p1 )
{
    std::cout << "the value of the smart pointer 1: " << *p1 << '\n';
}
if ( p2 )
{
    std::cout << "the value of the smart pointer 2: " << *p2 << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are passing the `unique_ptr` object to `cout` which wont know what to do with it as there is no appropriate overload available. If you want the pointer value to be printed then you need to do it like this:

```
std::cout << "P: " << (void *)p1.get() << std::endl;
```

If you want to print the value, that it points to, you can of course do it like this:

```
std::cout << "*P: " << *p1 << std::endl;
```

But in case of `p2` you will dereference a `nullptr` which is invalid causing undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that there is no `operator <<` overload for a `std::unique_ptr`. What you can do instead is

```
std::cout << "smart pointer dereferenced: " << *p1 << '\n';
```

Note that this is undefined behaviour if the smart pointer is in its null state.

As a side note, consider using `std::make_unique<int>(42)` to initialize a `std::unique_ptr` (if C++14 is available), as it encapsulates the raw `new`.

Comment: Or `p1.get()` if you interested in actual pointer value.

Comment: Well, this is in @Devolus answer :) Will not add that. Might just be the better answer.